# Boosting Timeouts in gitpod

Tags: git, github, gitpod

How do I boost the timeout window in gitpod? I use an `Unlimited plan`

The documentation specifically says you can extend up to `180 minutes`

Documentation Link : [Life of a Workspace - Timeouts](https://www.gitpod.io/docs/life-of-workspace/#timeouts)

I am unable to figure out how to set it up do to lack of documentation. Can someone guide me through?

The status bar in the bottom :

[image]

My current plan below.

[image]

Comment: Please at least mention cross-posting: https://community.gitpod.io/t/boosting-timeouts-in-gitpod/1114

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find an hourglass icon [image: hourglass icon] on the right in the status bar (at the bottom of the window). Click this icon and the timeout of this particular workspace is extended.

Comment: I do not have that please check the question updated with the screenshot can you please let me know if I have to install anything?

Comment: Since is it more a support request we will handle it here: https://community.gitpod.io/t/boosting-timeouts-in-gitpod/1114

Answer (score 1):

You can reach for this setting from multiple places.

- profile link as shown in the screenshot or just search for action "Extend Workspace Timeout"

[image]